# Unexpected indentation

Tags: python, indentation

I'm not sure as to why the last line printed is indented, any help will be much appreciated.

```
    def Task9():
        list1 = []
        n = int(input("Enter width of latin square: "))
        for x in range(1,n):
            list1.append(x)

        for x in range(n):
                print(" ".join( str(e)for e in list1[x:]) ," ".join( str(e) for e in list1[:x]))

    Task9()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an extra space in that last line for the same reason there's an extra space in **every** line. Join visibly to see it, for example with "X" instead of " ":

```
1X2X3X4X5X6 
2X3X4X5X6 1
3X4X5X6 1X2
4X5X6 1X2X3
5X6 1X2X3X4
6 1X2X3X4X5
 1X2X3X4X5X6
```

Answer (score 0):

This was kind of interesting, but it seems like you've stumbled upon an automated space insertion when printing multiple variables/strings. Combined with a tuple print issue, if using Python version 2.x.

```
print('hi', 'there')
print 'what', 'now?'
print('nothing')
```

In my Python v.2.7.10 this outputs:

```
('hi', 'there')
what now?
nothing
```

Notice how the first includes parens, and shows that this is actually a tuple of two strings, not a print function? Using `from __future__ import print_function` we would disallow the version without parens, but space will still be inserted between elements.

### Alternative versions

To remove the space you could use `print('{}{}'.format(" ".join(... [x:]), " ".join(... [:x])))`. But this would remove the wanted space between the two parts. Inserting it in the format string would reintroduce the unwanted space in the last line.

A better option is to sum up the two slices before joining and printing them:

```
for x in range(n):
    print(" ".join(str(e) for e in (list1[x:] + list1[:x])))
```

Another version using itertools instead of summing the slices:

```
import itertools
for x in range(n):
    print(" ".join(str(e) for e in itertools.chain(list1[x:], list1[:x])))
```

Both these versions produce the intended output, and I think it's a matter of preferences which to use. The first does however not require any imports, and is quite concise.